# phonegap code get the full path of a file to post in html

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am making a phonegap app for a offline books app. Here i am saving some files in a folder in the root of the device and display all the files in that folder for user to choose. when user clicks on a file to load it i am taking the full path of the file and giving to another javascript function to load it.

The files are saved in myappfolder in the root of the phone and i am getting the file path currectly.
My code is below:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
function(fileSystem) {    
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("myappfolder",
    {
        create: true
    }, function(directory) {
        var directoryReader = directory.createReader();
        directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {             
        if(entries.length > 0 ) {
            for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                var name = entries[i].name;
                var div1 = document.createElement('div');
                div1.className = 'books';
                div1.id = entries[i].fullPath;
                div1.innerHTML =  entries[i].name +'<hr>';
                document.getElementById('content'). appendChild(div1);
                div1.onclick =function (){
                    redirect(this.id);
                }
            }           
        }
```

When i use this code to load the file i get

```
network error in file://myappfolder/file.jpg
```

Kindly help me in solving this as i am new to phonegap.

I am passing this file to another js function which will display this file in a flip book format, It is working fine for me if i give a static file in the app folder

Comment: Hello any solution for this issue. Today i even tried to apend the entries[i].fullPath to a img src. but the image is not loading. so far i am using only images. . .

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research i found the solution:

The fullPath gives the path only from the root directory, But if you give

> entries[i].toNativeUrl

It is giving the complete path of the file The result of the above code is

> file:///storage/emulated/0/myappfolder/name.pdf.

This result came in my phone(samsung galaxy s4)

it works fine in iphone also.

Hope this helps some one else.